# Why do we need "serialize" model field attribute?

Tags: django

In `django.db.models.fields.__init__.py` there is a class `Field`, that is inherited by `CharFeld` and others and takes some boolean `serialize` attribute

```
class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, ... serialize=True, ...):
        ...
```

I can not find docs about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#field-attribute-reference

So, why is it here and is it safe to rely on it in some custom serialization technics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used by the [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/). These are used by the `loaddata` and `dumpdata` command, which can be used for two main purposes: fixtures and loading/dumping from one database to the next, which can be from different vendors.

It's used to determine if the field should be serialized or not. There's some complex logic in a model's Meta class initialization that determines whether a primary key should be serialized. If you want to figure out why, look at the callers of `setup_pk()` method in `django.db.models.options.Options` (`_prepare` and `add_field`).

The logic that reads this property resides in `django.core.serializer.base.Serializer.serialize()`.